# Magento 2 Widget With Image Chooser

Tags: magento2, widgets

So am working on a widget which allows the client to choose an image from their library of images and then insert it into the widget's params. [Here](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/cedricblondeau/6174911fb4bba6cb4943/raw/05fd632b6595886119f2dffa85c2282482bc035e/ImageChooser.php) is the block class code I am using for the image chooser and below is the widget parameter declaration in `widget.xml`

```
<parameter name="widget_image_chooser" xsi:type="block" visible="true" sort_order="20" required="true">
    <label translate="true">Category</label>
    <block class="Company\Module\Block\Widget\Image\Chooser">
        <data>
            <item name="button" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="open" xsi:type="string">Select Image</item>
            </item>
        </data>
    </block>
</parameter>
```

Now the problem is when the widget is inserted to a CMS Page or Block, it is inserted as a media widget instance, breaking the code because there can't be double quotes within double quotes, see below.

```
{{widget type="Company\Module\Block\Widget\LityVideo" identifier="https://vimeo.com/169559548" widget_image_chooser="{{media url="wysiwyg/13876414_1349854728361522_4781756811153391947_n.jpg"}}"}}
```

Is there a way of solving this without having to use javascript? I haven't been able to find the Model which renders the widgets in the CMS in the backend.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There seems to be a lot of people looking for a solution for this so here is my solution to my own answer.

The first thing you need to do is create a new plugin (interceptor) under `[COMPANY]/[MODULE]/etc/di.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Widget\Model\Widget">
        <plugin name="test1" type="[COMPANY]\[MODULE]\Model\Widget" sortOrder="1" disabled="false"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

Then create the interceptor logic, you need to use the before method, this way you can change the parameters being passed to `\Magento\Widget\Model\Widget`, `getWidgetDeclaration` so something like this.

```
namespace [COMPANY]\[MODULE]\Model;

use \Magento\Widget\Model\Widget as BaseWidget;

class Widget
{
    public function beforeGetWidgetDeclaration(BaseWidget $subject, $type, $params = [], $asIs = true)
    {
        // I rather do a check for a specific parameters
        if(key_exists("widget_image_chooser", $params)) {

            $url = $params["widget_image_chooser"];
            if(strpos($url,'/directive/___directive/') !== false) {

                $parts = explode('/', $url);
                $key   = array_search("___directive", $parts);
                if($key !== false) {

                    $url = $parts[$key+1];
                    $url = base64_decode(strtr($url, '-_,', '+/='));

                    $parts = explode('"', $url);
                    $key   = array_search("{{media url=", $parts);
                    $url   = $parts[$key+1];

                    $params["widget_image_chooser"] = $url;
                }
            }
        }

        return array($type, $params, $asIs);
    }
}
```

Comment: In Magento 2.3.5 you can use param 'force_static_path' = 1 for fix links on front instead of your plugin. But you need to create new plugin to set this param. See  https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/13c18d0b3f2e3fa53b317db5452eaab3d28dbeca/app/code/Magento/Cms/Controller/Adminhtml/Wysiwyg/Images/OnInsert.php#L47

Answer (score 1):

A improved solution to this as of magento 2.2.2 would be to do the below. within the plugin, to filter the directive for frontend use.

[COMPANY][MODULE]\etc\di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Widget\Model\Widget">
        <plugin name="test1" type="[COMPANY]\[MODULE]\Model\Widget" sortOrder="1" disabled="false"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

[COMPANY][MODULE]\Model\Widget.php

```
namespace [COMPANY]\[MODULE]\Model;

use \Magento\Widget\Model\Widget as BaseWidget;

class Widget
{
    protected $_filter;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Cms\Model\Template\Filter $filter
    )
    {
        $this->_filter = $filter;
    }

    public function beforeGetWidgetDeclaration(BaseWidget $subject, $type, $params = [], $asIs = true)
    {

        if ($type == "[COMPANY]\[MODULE]\Block\Widget\[ELEMENT CLASS]") {
            // I rather do a check for a specific parameters
            foreach ($params as $paramKey => $value) {

                $url = $params[$paramKey];
                if (strpos($url, '/directive/___directive/') !== false) {

                    $parts = explode('/', $url);
                    $key = array_search("___directive", $parts);
                    if ($key !== false) {

                        $url = $parts[$key + 1];
                        $url = base64_decode(strtr($url, '-_,', '+/='));

                        $parts = explode('"', $url);
                        $key = array_search("{{media url=", $parts);
                        $url = $parts[$key + 1];

                        $imagePath = $this->_filter->filter($url);
                        $params[$paramKey] = $imagePath;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return array($type, $params, $asIs);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For Magento 2.3.5 and newer, that issue can be solved in a simple but not very obvious way.
In the Image\Chooser class, it is necessary to add the following line to the text input element definition:

```
$input->addCustomAttribute('data-force_static_path', 1);
```

That will force the Media Browser to generate static links related to the website root (starting from /media).

Answer (score -1):

Thanks for posting your solution. It did not do what I excpected it to do.
For me, it changed the `$params['widget_image_chooser']` value to: `wysiwyg/Boat.jpg`. Ofcourse you can use this in your template.

Because I do not know the consequences of changing the url, I used your interceptor to replace the double quotes by single quotes. For me, this solves my problem.

My modified interceptor:

```
public function beforeGetWidgetDeclaration(BaseWidget $subject, $type, $params = [], $asIs = true)
{
    $imageParmeterName = 'photo'; //The parameter name as defined in widget.xml

    // I rather do a check for a specific parameters
    if (key_exists($imageParmeterName, $params)) {

        $url = $params[$imageParmeterName];
        if (strpos($url, '/directive/___directive/') !== false) {

            $parts = explode('/', $url);
            $key = array_search("___directive", $parts);
            if ($key !== false) {

                $key++;
                $url = $parts[$key];
                $imgSrc = base64_decode(strtr($url, '-_,', '+/=')); //{{media url="wysiwyg/Boat.jpg"}}
                $imgSrc = str_replace('"', "'", $imgSrc); //Replace " with ' to avoid breaking html
                $parts[$key] = base64_encode($imgSrc); //{{media url='wysiwyg/Boat.jpg'}}
                $url = implode('/', $parts); //Rebuild url

                $params[$imageParmeterName] = $url;
            }
        }
    }

    return array($type, $params, $asIs);
}
```

Edit: It seems this does not work as intended for some reason.
Eventhough I do not modify the structure of the url, this 'solution' causes a backend image link to appear on the frontend.. I suspect this might be another issue.

Comment: Yeah i got the backend image link issue, was only in production however within my dev area everything seemed fine. Did you ever solve that?