# Magento 2 - Use of the Media Image Uploader

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, image-upload, widgets

I created a new Block that renders a button to upload an image via Magento's `Mediabrowserutility`. This Module is also used for uploading images to a CMS Page. The Block is used to add Image Uploads to a Widget.

The Block Code is the following:

```
/**
 * Prepare chooser element HTML
 *
 * @param Element $element
 * @return Element
 */
public function prepareElementHtml(Element $element)
{
    $config = $this->_getData('config');
    $sourceUrl = $this->getUrl('cms/wysiwyg_images/index',
        ['target_element_id' => $element->getId(), 'type' => 'file']);

    /** @var \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Button $chooser */
    $chooser = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Button')
                    ->setType('button')
                    ->setClass('btn-chooser')
                    ->setLabel($config['button']['open'])
                    ->setOnClick('MediabrowserUtility.openDialog(\'' . $sourceUrl . '\', 0, 0, "MediaBrowser", {})')
                    ->setDisabled($element->getReadonly());

    /** @var \Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\Text $input */
    $input = $this->_elementFactory->create("text", ['data' => $element->getData()]);
    $input->setId($element->getId());
    $input->setForm($element->getForm());
    $input->setClass("widget-option input-text admin__control-text");
    if ($element->getRequired()) {
        $input->addClass('required-entry');
    }

    $element->setData('after_element_html', $input->getElementHtml()
        . $chooser->toHtml() . "<script>require(['mage/adminhtml/browser']);</script>");

    return $element;
}
```

As you see, the onClick Event triggers the MediaBrowser. I am able to use the MediaBrowser as expected, but as soon as I save the whole widget, the URLs from the Image refer to an image that is not reachable in the frontend, because an admin session is required.

This is what the URLs look like:

```
http://example.com/adm_folder/cms/wysiwyg/directive/___directive/e3ttZWRpYSB1cmw9Ind5c2l3eWcvanVsYm8vanVsYm8taG9tZS1zbGlkZS10ZXN0LmpwZyJ9fQ,,/key/b6dbd3aad4f2f5657f0c96d1ec948c30e543d5bd488274890670a408605b669c/
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create a plugin to the class `Magento\Widget\Model\Widget`. See my original post & answer [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/131262/magento-2-widget-with-image-chooser/135233#135233)

The first thing you need to do is create a new plugin (interceptor) under `[COMPANY]/[MODULE]/etc/di.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Widget\Model\Widget">
        <plugin name="test1" type="[COMPANY]\[MODULE]\Model\Widget" sortOrder="1" disabled="false"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

Then create the interceptor logic, you need to use the before method, this way you can change the parameters being passed to `\Magento\Widget\Model\Widget`, `getWidgetDeclaration` so something like this.

```
namespace [COMPANY]\[MODULE]\Model;

use \Magento\Widget\Model\Widget as BaseWidget;

class Widget
{
    public function beforeGetWidgetDeclaration(BaseWidget $subject, $type, $params = [], $asIs = true)
    {
        // I rather do a check for a specific parameters
        if(key_exists("widget_image_chooser", $params)) {

            $url = $params["widget_image_chooser"];
            if(strpos($url,'/directive/___directive/') !== false) {

                $parts = explode('/', $url);
                $key   = array_search("___directive", $parts);
                if($key !== false) {

                    $url = $parts[$key+1];
                    $url = base64_decode(strtr($url, '-_,', '+/='));

                    $parts = explode('"', $url);
                    $key   = array_search("{{media url=", $parts);
                    $url   = $parts[$key+1];

                    $params["widget_image_chooser"] = $url;
                }
            }
        }

        return array($type, $params, $asIs);
    }
}
```

Comment: Finally :D That is what I needed :) Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I've been trying to get this to work without much luck.
I'm preparing my image in `Block\Widget\BannerWidget.php`. The field returns 
`public function getImage()
    {
        $url = $this->getData('banner_image');
        return $url;
    }`